# Maintain users data integrity across multiple databases for ASP.NET

Tags: asp.net, sql, sql-server, database

I have 2 questions.
I am developing a ASP.NET web application that uses the standard ASP.NET membership. We intend to have the membership tables in 1 database. We have 2 other databases that stores data for 2 different applications.

```
Shared - Membership info
DB1 - Application1
DB2 - Application2
```

Both applications uses the membership info in the "Shared" database.
The Shared database has a table called userdetals that will store additional users' info such as name, phone and job title for example.

However, DB1 also has a table called employees that store the same fields as name, phone and job title. Each employee may be an user.

Also for each table in DB1 and DB2, we keep audit trial, i.e. which user updated the tables in the database. Hence, we need to store UserID in the tables of DB1 and DB2.
We thought of having a Users table added in DB1 and DB2. So everytime a new user is created in Shared, the same user will be created in Users table in DB1 and DB2.

Our questions are:

1. What is the best way to maintain database integrity given the above setup? E.g. Each employee is assigned as an user. If any fields in DB1 such as username, name and phone is updated, then the same fields in Shared DB should be updated and vice versa.
2. Is it advisable to have membership database in a different database in our case? What is the best solution since almost all the tables in DB1 and DB2 references userID in the Shared database.

Comment: What version of SQL Server are you using?

Answer (score 2):

1.
The technology you are looking for is Merge Replication (http://bit.ly/KUtkPl). Essentially, you would create a common Users table on both databases, create a Merge Replication **publisher** on one application database, and then create a Merge Replication **subscriber** on the other application database.  You could also set this up to synchronize the schema as well (which also means you only need to create the table once on the publishing database: it will push the table, schema with data, to the subscriber).

But if you are looking for more of a manual approach, I would not denormalize the user data to the employee(s) table, instead create a supplemental table and a view on each Application server.  Kind of like inheritance in OOP:  Any common data between the Employee table and Users table, leave on the shared user table.  Any unique columns for the Employee, add to the supplemental table only and store on each database.  The view would merge both the supplemental table and shared table. (http://bit.ly/9KPxt0)

Even if you do use Replication Services, I would still use this view design with the synchronized table.

You COULD update through the view, but I would not recommend that.  It has been done before successfully in production, but there are too many constraints that could blow up (http://bit.ly/LJCJev).  Instead update the table directly that holds the data.

Absolutely avoid "triggers that synchronize".  Too risky (can cause an infant loop on your SQL server) and too much maintenance overhead.

2.
I would do the Merge Replication, it is just less for you to worry about and maintain after it is configured correctly.  But your approach is OK if want something more manual or if you are not familiar with Replication services in SQL... just use the view noted above and you'll be set.

Comment: I really appreciate your sharing. If I want to expand this into a multi-tenancy application whereby the "Shared" database contains all the users from various tenants. Each tenant will have its own Database, e.g. Tenant1_DB1, Tenant2_DB1, etc. Would manual as you mentioned above work better or replication. It seems to me that for replication, I would not be able to maintain a Shared database for multi-tenancy application. Thanks for your inputs.

Comment: Secondly, if we choose the manual method, we will need to create a "Users" table in DB1 and DB2 as well so that if a user is deleted or modified, the "Users" table in DB1 and DB2 will be modified?

Comment: So the same DB1 can be called DB1a in the future...   CREATE VIEW [dbo].[YourView]
as
select 
a.ID, 
a.SomeInfo, 
b.SomeOtherInfo
from TableInA a
join DatabaseB.dbo.TableInB b

Comment: Replication would work better....  But if you use the Employee table to only list who is an employee at each location/database (where the employee table has two columns: employeeID, userID), then I can see a use for the view.  The view could also be used if you have another supplemental table that uses the USERS table for a base.  Example: if you had a Management table and an Employee table, but they both shared a common Users table.

Comment: The view is either going to point to a table within the database (if you have replication services) or to a table on the shared DB (if you do not).

Comment: I would put the full name for TableInA in your CREATE VIEW query... just in case.  I am assuming that DatabaseB is the shared database. Also make sure you set your JOIN ... *ON* ... clause.

Comment: Ok, our problem is with View is that the database name is not fixed. The shared database name is fixed but not the application database, e.g. DB1, DB2 an be called DB1a, DB2a...etc. so how do we construct a view in such an instance?

Comment: The view would be constructed on each application database, NOT on the shared.  So when you create the view, use what ever name for the database/table you wish.  Construct the view relative to the database that it is on.

Comment: Thanks. We decided on the manual approach as SQL Express only supports replication for subscriber only and some deployments maybe on SQL Express. Greatly appreciate your prompt assistance.

Answer (score 0):

Easy way:

You can create link server to these databases.
And then create synonym to easy access to tables of each database.
Create trigger to update data when any data was updated on each table.